Console closes right after I run my program, how do I fix it?
I'm new to Python, so it may be a silly question, but I made an .exe file from my .py project via PyInstaller, but when I run it, it closes instantly.
It runs perfectly fine as .py file in PyCharm and VS, so there shouldn't be any mistakes.
I've already tried all kinds of input() at the end of main program, rn it's like this (yes I'm that desperate):
while(True):
    out = input("You want to exit now? y/n  ")
    if out == 'y':
        print("Goodbye!")
        break

So even an infinite loop doesn't stop it, it just won't let user even write y/n, it closes instantly, but I can see it print all the prints I have in my program.
Also tried this and also tried running it in windows console, still nothing (by the way when i tried runinng it it windows console, it opened a new console window).
Thank you in advance!

If you run any executable that just outputs something to the screen an then terminates, Windows will close the window after it completes. Either run it from a batch file with a pause added, or add some code to your script that waits for user input before terminating (like a basic input('Press Enter.'))

Did you remake the exe file with the new python file after editing it?

Run the .exe from an already-open command prompt (rather than by double-clicking it), so that you can see whatever error message is causing it to exit prematurely.  If your code deals with files at all, a likely cause of problems would be  a difference in current working directory, as compared to running the .py directly.

@Grismar I've already tried that "input(...)" thing and even modified it to a code in my question, because it didn;t work.
About batch-file: how do I make it from my project and would it work on devices that don't have python or IDE installed?

@jasonharper as I've already mentioned, I've tried running it from console, but it opened a new one. How do I run it without it opening a new window?

PyInstaller executables won't cause the opening of a new window by default, so it's likely a side effect of the rest of your code. You've only shared the bit of code you used to prevent the script from closing, but it's unclear what the rest of the scripts does, or how you created it. Writing a simple 'hello world' script that prints a text, waits for input, and gets built with --onefile runs without issue from console, and will wait for user input before closing the window when launched from the Explorer. You need to provide more details on your process.
